# Exporting methods versus objects versus class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am wondering about the "correct" way to export functionality in TypeScript project.

I need a module with some simple caching functionality: setting key->value, querying and unsetting. I see at least 4 ways to do this:

**1. Exporting pure methods**

```
export const set = async (token: string, user: IUser): Promise<boolean> => {...};
export const get = async (token: string): Promise<IUser> => {...};
export const unset = async (token: string): Promise<IUser> => {...};
```

**2. Exporting object literal**

```
export const cache = {
  set: async (token: string, user: IUser): Promise<boolean> => {...},
  get: async (token: string): Promise<IUser> => {...},
  unset: async (token: string): Promise<boolean> => {...},
};
```

**3. Exporting class**

```
export class Cache {
   set, get, unset....
}
```

**4. Exporting class instance**

```
class Cache {
   set, get, unset....
}
export const cache = new Cache();
```

Which are the factors I should consider before deciding on the best approach?
Pros/cons of each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **first example** you encapsulate related methods in a module. And it makes sense to simply export these methods one by one from their module (its a basic feature of ES Modules).
And you can get quite flexible importing this methods:

```
import { set } from './your-module'
```

OR

```
import * as cache from './your-module'
```

The **second example** is also OK, since you group related methods in a single object. But if `cache` was the only thing I was going to export from this module I would use a default export:

```
const cache = ...

export default cache
```

In the **third example** it would make sense to export this as a class if you expect to use multiple instances of this class where each instance has a different configuration. Also, if your methods need to access some common state (e.g. a shared object), classes make relationships between the properties and methods explicit. And if there is some state, it's easy to free up the memory used by that state by simply deleting the instance that keeps it.

In the **fourth example** you make sure that there is a single instance of the Cache class and the reference to this instance will always remain in your module. Again this makes sense if you would like to group some functionality that has some common state.

If a module is stateless (it has no data to keep and share between the functions it exports) I would use the first approach. If there is some common state and logic that should be shared between the functions, I think using either the functional way or the OOP way would be fine (it would depend on the structure and code style of the project and the preferences of the team).

Answer (score 0):

1. It does not make sense to having only one method without others. They come together.
2. **Good one**
3. Does it make sense to have 2 instances of Cache class?
4. Class does not produce any benefit compared to 2